# Robust Similarity Measure for template matching

Tags: measure-theory

I am now working on a specific pattern recognition(template matching) problem. Say I have a data bank with 5000 atom signals (entries in dictionary), each atom signal is an complex signal with length 1000 (can be interpreted as an vector with dimension 1000). Each of the complex signal corresponds to certain personal information (Telephone, birthday etc..).

Now there is an measured signal (it can be interpreted as unknown atom signal mixed with gaussian noise.). We now do the template matching by finding the maximal Inner-product (dot product of two vectors) of the measured signal and the signals in the data bank. However I believe there must be a more robust (e.g Kernel Method) template matching method which might use the information about the data structure in the data bank itself. In which direction shall check in order to come up with a better method

It would be great if someone can help me with that!